# Java Buffer - Cannot send object with length bigger than 20kb

Tags: java, buffer, limit

I don't know why, but cannot send objects with length bigger than 20,000 bytes. I like length of buffer is lower than remaining. How can I fix that? Using Grizzly and Ambassador libraries. While sending small values everything is ok.

System outputs

1. [05:44:04 INFO]: 14480
2. [05:44:04 INFO]: STOPED3   14480 < 20636
3. [05:44:04 INFO]: 20557
4. [05:44:04 INFO]: STOPED2   20557 < 1229410144

My Code:

```
private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 12;

@Override
public NextAction handleRead(final FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException {
    final Buffer buffer = ctx.getMessage();
    System.out.println(buffer.limit());
    final int total = buffer.remaining();
    if (total < HEADER_SIZE) {
        System.out.println("STOPED1 "+"  "+total+" < "+HEADER_SIZE);
        return ctx.getStopAction(buffer);
    }
    buffer.get();
    buffer.get();
    buffer.get();
    buffer.get();
    int len = buffer.getInt();
    if (total < HEADER_SIZE + len) {
        System.out.println("STOPED2 "+"  "+total+" < "+(HEADER_SIZE+len));
        return ctx.getStopAction(buffer);
    }
    byte[] pack = new byte[len];
    buffer.get(pack);
    String name = new String(pack);
    int size = buffer.getInt();
    final int completeMessageLength = HEADER_SIZE + size + len;
    if (total < completeMessageLength) {
        System.out.println("STOPED3 "+"  "+total+" < "+completeMessageLength);
        return ctx.getStopAction(buffer);
    }
    final Buffer remainder = total > completeMessageLength ? buffer.split(completeMessageLength) : null;
    System.out.println("PACKET[IN] Name: " + name + " Size: " + total + " BodySize: " + buffer.remaining());
    byte[] body = new byte[size];
    buffer.get(body);
    Packet packet = null;
    try {
        packet = getPacket(name);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (packet == null) {
        return ctx.getInvokeAction(remainder);
    }
    packet.read(body);
    handlePacket(ctx.getConnection(), packet);
    return ctx.getInvokeAction(remainder);
}

@Override
public NextAction handleWrite(final FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException {
    Packet packet = ctx.getMessage();
    String name = packet.getClass().getName();
    byte[] packetBody = name.getBytes();
    byte[] body = packet.write();
    int bodyLen = body.length;
    int packetLen = packetBody.length;
    final MemoryManager memoryManager = ctx.getConnection().getTransport().getMemoryManager();
    int size = HEADER_SIZE + bodyLen + packetLen;
    final Buffer output = memoryManager.allocate(size);
    output.allowBufferDispose(true);
    output.put((byte) 0);
    output.put((byte) 0);
    output.put((byte) 0);
    output.put((byte) 0);
    output.putInt(packetLen);
    output.put(packetBody);
    output.putInt(bodyLen);
    output.put(body);
    ctx.setMessage(output.flip());
    System.out.println("PACKET[OUT] ID: " + name + " Size: " + size);
    return ctx.getInvokeAction();
}

protected static Packet getPacket(String name) throws IllegalAccessException {
    try {
        Class cl = Class.forName(name);
        return (Packet) cl.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


protected abstract void handlePacket(Connection connection, Packet packet);
```

Comment: What do your System.out.prinlns print?

Comment: [05:44:04 INFO]: 14480
[05:44:04 INFO]: STOPED3   14480 < 20636
[05:44:04 INFO]: 20557
[05:44:04 INFO]: STOPED2   20557 < 1229410144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above code,you don't retreat the `buffer` position while the condition is false :`if (total < HEADER_SIZE + len)` or `if (total < completeMessageLength)`.I think you should `mark()` the position before you read anything from the `bufffer`,and then ,if the `buffer` is not fully,you should `reset()` the position,in order to the `handleRead()` method can read data header correctly at next time.

In my guess,When the send data is less than 20000 bytes,the send data will not be splited into different packet,so the `handleRead()` will read fully bytes every times,but it will be splited into several packet while the send data is large,so the `handleRead()` may read a partion of the send data.